# Не добавляется в бд выдает ошибку

Tags: php, mysqli

Братья программисты проблема такая сделал пагинациию вытащил инфу из базы но добавление почему-то не работает выдает такую ошибку. bool(false) Ошибка подготовки запроса: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':name, :content, NOW())' at line 2

Надеюсь на вашу помощь братья по работе не могу понять что за ошибка))

```
////////////////////////////////////////////

    db.php


  <?php 
$host = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "Ors";
$dbarticles = "comments";
$connection = mysqli_connect("$host", "$dbuser", "$dbpassword", "$dbname");


        function addComents( $name, $content){
           global  $connection;
        $query = $connection->prepare("

            INSERT INTO comments (name, content, post_date)
            VALUES (:name, :content, NOW())
        ");

            var_dump ($query);

            if(!$query) {   echo "Ошибка подготовки запроса: " . mysqli_error($connection);   exit();




        $query->execute(
            array( 
                "name"=>$name,
                "content"=>$content 


            )
        );
        }
        }


?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105032/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Comment: А как в чате писать то теперь???????

Comment: Я сделал проверку выдало теперь такую ошибку. Ошибка подготовки запроса: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':name, :content, NOW())' at line 2

Comment: Я только что нашел ошибку но не знаю как сообщить об этом Денису который мне помогал так как не знаю как писать в чат, что же мне предлагаете теперь делать????

Comment: Так кто-нибудь ответит как писать в чат, вообщем если что Денис я попробовал что вы написали проверку  sql и мне выдало такую ошибку, Ошибка подготовки запроса: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':name, :content, NOW())' at line 2.  Надеюсь вы поможете и скажете что делать дальше, заранее  благодарствую за вашу помощь!

Comment: По идее у вас должна быть возможность писать в чат, в который перемещены комментарии. По идее надо просто перейти по ссылке и писать сообщение внизу экрана. Чтобы адресат вашего комментария получил уведомление о вашем сообщении - упомяните его имя через `@`. По сути вопроса - попробуйте написать так: `INSERT INTO comments (name, content, post_date)
            VALUES (:name, :content, NOW())`

Comment: у меня почему-то нельзя в чат писать я уже везде все облазил доступа нет везде все проверил писать негде и да то что вы написали я уже пробывал не помогло как мне вновь выйти на контакт с Денисом чтобы он дальше помог решить мою проблему?

Comment: Возможно вам репутации не хватало. Попробуйте теперь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105043/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: @Denis640Kb я написал ваш код для выявления ошибки sql, вот результат выдало такую ошибку, Ошибка подготовки запроса: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':name, :content, NOW())' at line 2. Что делать дальше в чем же заключается проблема???????

Comment: Это сообщение перенеслось в чат??

Comment: Может мне снова задать вопрос и все???

Comment: Вы пробовали предложенное мной исправление? С убиранием ID из запроса? Новый вопрос можно, если он будет отличаться от этого. Если будет повтор - то его просто закроют как дубликат и объединят с этим. Лучше через правку этот вопрос дополнить, добавив сообщения об ошибках в текст вопроса - в комментариях всё это теряется

Comment: Да пробовал и говорю же не помогло

Comment: Блин да где в чате писать вроде бы репутация позволяет но я до сих пор не могу найти куда писать там негде писать извиняюсь может я слепой но все же там негде писать

Comment: Что именно у вас в чате не работает? Не открывается ссылка? Открывается, но там пусто? Или ошибку какую-то пишет? Или у вас нет поля ввода? Или туда текст не вводится? Или не отправляется? Или отправляется, но не появляется в чате? Без описания проблемы вам сложно помочь.

Comment: Так же вам стоит добавить то, что у вас просили и что вы отвечали в текст вопроса через правку оного - так новые люди смогут узнать что вы уже выяснили без копания в уже 2 чатах (скоро, наверное, и 3 придётся делать, т.к. тут опять комменты набираются, а их модераторам приходится убирать, т.к. система ругается). Так же вам стоит убрать лишний код из вопроса - то что не относится к его сути. Чем меньше кода (если его достаточно) - тем выше вероятность получить ответ.

Comment: У меня нет поля ввода вот в чем проблема писать некуда, я уже все там облазил но так и не нашел куда писать ибо негде, я могу править код но по моему мнению там весь код важен не только файл db.php

Comment: Очень странно. Может у вас где-то справа есть кнопка типа "Войти в чат"? И на чём вы чат запускаете? Телефон/комп? Может там вёрстка поехала? Попробуйте по этому поводу в тех.поддержку написать - может быть они как-то смогут что-то прояснить. И во втором чате вам что-то написали по ошибке.

Comment: Я с лаптопа, окей напишу в тех под

Comment: bool(false) Ошибка подготовки запроса: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':name, :content, NOW())' at line 2.  Евгений выдало такую ошибку впрочем та же самая только добавилось bool (false)

Comment: Юрий я сократил код по вашему советую и многих других людей и уже написал в тех поддержку этого достаточно?

Comment: Ребят мне дали ответ я использовал синтаксис PDO,  а должен был mysqli так как везде его в коде использовал кроме db.php и add.com.php как теперь в db.php  правильный INSERT  написать с синтаксисом mysqli при этом используя функцию чтобы в add.com.php  вытащить ее, надеюсь на вашу помощь братцы заранее СПАСИБО))

Answer (score 3):

При работе с базой данных в РНР следует использовать синтаксис того расширения, которое используется для подключения. Смешивать синтаксис нельзя.

Если для подключения используется PDO, то следует использовать синтаксис PDO. Здесь можно посмотреть [пример запроса на вставку с помощью pdo](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert)

Если для подключения используется mysqli, то следует использовать синтаксис mysqli. Здесь можно посмотреть [пример запроса на вставку с помощью mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/insert)

Comment: Да я из-за пагинации использовал mysqli,  а так всегда использую PDO,я просто не знал как с PDO сделать пагинацию в интернете все примеры только с mysqli, сейчас попробую если получится оповещу вас заранее спасибо огромное вам

Comment: Много переадресаций пишет можете пожалуйста написать как надо правильно с функцией и с mysqli, я просто никогда с mysqli не работал, вот так написал но видимо не правильно.   function addComents( $name, $content){
           global  $connection;
  
            
            $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (name, content, post_date) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt= $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $content);
$stmt->execute(
           
   array( 
    "name"=>$name,
    "content"=>$content 
                
                
   )
  );
        }

Comment: можете ответить пожалуйста